# How to say that it takes 5 seconds for a car to achieve 100 km/h?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, speech

In Persian, we say that "0-to-100 of a car is x seconds". In other words, "0-to-100" is somehow a word on its own (also it is pronounced quite fast in Persian).

In [List of fastest production cars by acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fastest_production_cars_by_acceleration) on Wikipedia I see the expressions "0–100 km/h time" and "the car can accelerate to". So I think the following sentences can be used:

1. The 0–100 km/h time of this car is 5 seconds.
2. The car can accelerate to 100 km/h in 5 seconds.

Are these sentences correct? If yes, then how do you read/pronounce the expression "0–100 km/h time". What is/are the common expressions to use?

Comment: In the US it's "can do zero to a hundred in five seconds".  If the distance metric is not implied by the context it would be "hundred miles-per-hour" or "hundred kilometers-per hour".

Comment: @HotLicks I've not heard "can **do** zero to xxx," the way I've always heard it is "can **go** zero to xxx." Maybe a typo?

Comment: @MikeHarris - My impression is that "do" is more idiomatic.  Have not done a rigorous study, however.

Comment: @HotLicks Interesting, thanks. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't a typo!

Comment: @MikeHarris - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+zero+to%2C+do+zero+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20zero%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20zero%20to%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

For a British car, the upper limit is in miles per hour, and is usually 60mph due to legal speed restrictions.

As we would be talking about cars, 'mph' is assumed, and we say:

> 0 to 60 **in** 5 seconds.

Note the preposition used is **in** not **is**.

Comment: OP doesn't suggest that 'is' is a preposition. He asks whether "0-to-100"  is used as a nominal (like 'je ne sais quoi', for instance) in English.

Comment: ex.1 looks like he is using 'is'  as a prep. imo, like ex.2 doesn't give a range